# wp_list_comments() only returns when user is loged in

Tags: comments

```
<?php if (!is_user_logged_in()) { ?>
<p class="text-center">
برای ارسال نظر باید <a href="https://www. .com/login?redirect_to=<?php echo the_permalink();?>"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-sign-in"></i> وارد حساب کاربریتان شوید</a> یا <a href="/register"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user-plus"></i> عضو سایت شوید</a>
</p>
<?php } ?>

<?php

    $comments = get_comments(array(
        'post_id' => get_the_ID(),
        'orderby' => 'comment_date',
    ));
echo wp_list_comments("callback=wpsaz_comment&end-callback=dubfa_div&per_page=5",$comments);
?>
```

what is wrong with this code?

comments returns only when user is logged in.

how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If it is for the post, then check whether in the post settings have you allowed the comments should be displayed?

Also do check the settings at: /wp-admin/options-discussion.php

Answer (score -1):

Fixed!

the problem was because of $comments, i removed that and fixed.